# Vertical split in VIM Project plugin

Tags: vim, plugins, ide

I am using the VIM porject plugin ([here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69)) and I know that you can use the `\s` shortcut to open a file in a split window, but I was wondering if there is a way to a vertical split instead of a horizontal split. I couldn't seem to find anything about that online and would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such mapping built-in, and one has to modify the plugin itself because its mappings only apply to the project sidebar.

However, since the plugin is mature and there have been no changes since 2006, it's probably okay to directly extend the plugin. Adding the mapping itself is trivial:

```
--- project.vim.orig    2006-10-13 15:47:08.000000000 +0200
+++ project.vim 2016-11-03 11:10:17.691219204 +0100
@@ -1174,6 +1178,7 @@ function! s:Project(filename) " <<<
        " Mappings <<<
        nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <Return>   \|:call <SID>DoFoldOrOpenEntry('', 'e')<CR>
        nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <S-Return> \|:call <SID>DoFoldOrOpenEntry('', 'sp')<CR>
+        nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <LocalLeader>v \|:call <SID>DoFoldOrOpenEntry('', 'vsp')<CR>
        nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <C-Return> \|:call <SID>DoFoldOrOpenEntry('silent! only', 'e')<CR>
        nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <LocalLeader>T \|:call <SID>DoFoldOrOpenEntry('', 'tabe')<CR>
        nmap     <buffer> <silent> <LocalLeader>s <S-Return>
```